# Launch iPhone app from html onload

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, ios5

I have created an iPad application.

I want to launch it from safari. With URL Schema, it's done successfully.

From my application, I want to send a link. Which on click should open my app.

The mail which I have sent contains matter in the following way

> CLICK HERE TO LAUNCH APP

Which is an anchor tag whose href = "MyApp://someString".

But when I send this as mail, on iPad configured mail, link is working fine but in browsers it's not working. Then I came to know that Yahoo, Gmail will deactivate links other than starting with `http://`

Now, I want to open my app with URL schema `MyApp://` with HTML Onload similar to opening iTunes in our PC when itunes.apple.com is opened

With `windows.open('MyApp://')`, in the `onload()` function also, my app is not launching.

How to do that?
How to launch my app when html is loading?

Comment: You seem to have two questions here. 1. Links to open your app don’t work in Yahoo mail and GMail. 2. You can’t open your app from `window.onload`. You should ask them separately.

Comment: “With `windows.open('MyApp://')`, in the `onload()` function also, my app is not launching.” — Have you tried `window.open('MyApp://')`, i.e. without the `s` on the end of `window`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a PHP page like this:

```
<?php
 header("Location: MyApp://somestring;")(
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; MyApp://somestring" />
  <title>Opening App...</title>
  <script>
   function openApp() {
    window.location.href = "MyApp://somestring";
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="openApp();">
  <a href="MyApp://somestring">Click here if app doesn't open...</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just `<?php
 header("Location: MyApp://somestring;")(
?>`

is enough to open the URL. No need of onload() function.

Comment: It's better to be redundant. Just in case one method doesn't work, there are plenty more there. Surely one of them will work.

Comment: @TaruniNeema Hi, am a bit late here. Could you be so kind and explain why and how this works? Did the answerer mean to put all this in the mail from you app? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig.. I have created a PHP file with the above script & hosted in my website. And, I am using the link of that PHP file with few parameters.

Comment: @TaruniNeema Could you also be so kind as to show the part how you can use the link of the PHP with a few parameters? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig You could make a link like `http://example.com/launchMyApp.php` which is a PHP script containing the above code.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt any online email client would let you run javascript in the email. It would be extremely insecure. If they refuse to handle any other URL schema than HTTP, it is probably because of the same security concerns.

I would work around the problem by having a link like

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/open-app?schema=MyApp">CLICK HERE TO LAUNCH APP</a>
```

Then the page on your server would just print out

```
<script>
    window.location.href="<?= $_GET['schema'] ?>://";
</script>
```

(Example in PHP)

**Just make sure to scrub the schema variable before you print it!**

You could use a regex to make sure it only has a-z, or something like that. Otherwise you get the same security problems Yahoo and Gmail are avoiding.

Comment: for e.g., `http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8` . When you click on this link, it will open your AppStore.
Similarly, I want to do it in the same way.
Once the html is loaded, it is automatically opening the AppStore in your device.

Comment: I bet Apple is doing the same PHP trick (or is it 'WebObjects?) that Geon just suggested.

Comment: @ranReloaded.. You are right. Apple is doing the same trick. If network is not available, then AppStore is not launched.